# Phaser P2 body.collideWorldBounds stops body collisions

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser 2.4.2 with P2 physics. I have a sort of jar shaped body containing some circular bodies (balls). I want to move the jar offscreen but the balls are colliding with the world bounds.
I tried setting `collideWorldBounds` on the balls like so:

```
ball.body.setCircle(64);
ball.body.collideWorldBounds = false;
```

but this stops them colliding with the jar which I want -- the result is gravity makes them drop offscreen.

You can see a demo here: https://output.jsbin.com/vuyexo
Click the red button to make the jar move.
Uncomment `collideWorldBounds=false` in the 'balls' section.

Why is this happening and how can I make the balls collide with the jar body but not the world bounds when the jar is moved offscreen?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the P2 world bounds using `setBoundsToWorld` so like this

```
//..
game.physics.p2.gravity.y = 300;
game.physics.p2.setBoundsToWorld(false, false, true, true); // left=false, right=false, top=true, bottom=true
```

Alternatively you could just make the P2 world larger, so for example make the width 2000 instead of 768.

```
game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 2000, 1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default p2 collides everything with everything else, but if you want it to do something different then you have to explicitly list which objects collide with each other by adding each body to a collision group and then calling body.collides like this:

```
        var jarCG = this.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();
        var ballsCG = this.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();
        jar.body.setCollisionGroup(jarCG);
        jar.body.collides(ballsCG);
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            var ball = balls.create(250+(i%3)*128,300+Math.floor(i/3)*128);
            ball.body.setCircle(64);
            ball.body.debug = true;
            ball.body.collideWorldBounds = false;
            ball.body.setCollisionGroup(ballsCG);
            ball.body.collides([jarCG, ballsCG]);
        }
```

This is working for me, but using a tween to move the jar still makes the physics act weird. You can fix it by either using jar.body.velocity.x instead of tweening or by also tweening all the balls. You can also try tweening stack.x if you just want to move the sprites, but for some reason this isn't moving their bodies.